# Python - store two API values into variables

Tags: python, json, api

I wan't to store two API values into 2 different variable, this is what my code looks like:

```
@app.route('/bflipper', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bFlipper():
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[cannot show key]').json()
    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["sell_summary"][:1], #I want to store this
            "buy_price": product["buy_summary"][:1], # and this
            "sell_volume": product["quick_status"]["sellVolume"],
            "buy_volume": product["quick_status"]["buyVolume"],
        }
        for product in f["products"].values()
    ]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userInput = request.form['coins']
        return render_template("flipper.html", userInput=userInput, products=products)
    else:
        return render_template("flipper.html")
```

I want to store "sell_price" and "buy_price" into two different variables, then be able to return them to my HTML file, how do I do this?

I tried to do:

sellPrice = products[2] & products[3] (for buyPrice)

But doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable "products" is a list that contains one dict object.
In order to access its first element you need

```
products[0]
```

and in order to get a key in that element, you need:

```
products[0]["sell_price"]
```

that will give you the value of the key "sell_price".

I am not sure about the intention of the line that comes after the first object...

```
for product in f["products"].values()
```

All it can do if just go over all the values that are in the key "products" inside f. without the ability to know which is which.

However, I am not sure where you want to return it but you need to build your html file with them in it.

Comment: The goal is not really to return it yet, I am trying to give user the product that they can make the most profit of depending on what value of "coins" they put in, I will give it a try! Thanks :)

Comment: np, please see my edit, I only saw that part after posting. good luck

Comment: Seem to be working just fine! The only issue is that I need to grab "pricePerUnit" inside of "sell_price", and it consists of "amount", "orders" and "pricePerUnit". I can't just add ["pricePerUnit"] after my sell_price item, as I get the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, and I tried doing "[0]" in between, but then I get an indexError: list index out of range, what should I do?

Comment: I dont know the object inside,products[0]["sell_price"] it might not be a dict, it can just be a string and then u can't just access "pricePerUnit" as a key.
try to print the value, and the value type and see whats in it. if it is a string that represents a json u can try to get it out using the json library and the function Loads. try to read about it a bit. and alwyse print ur work